# How to pass Firebase Auth Token from client to server?

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

The website that I'm working on uses Firebase authentication and different users that login have different permissions as to which pages they can visit.

The way signing in is setup is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882626/firebase-admin-sdk-create-user-and-send-verification-email):

1. User Logins in with two parameters - "id" and "email"
2. Server uses these to create a custom "uid", then uses the Firebase Admin SDK to create a custom token that is sent back to the client.
3. The client logs in with the Javascript Firebase SDK - firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken()
4. Now that the user is logged in, they can click different pages - i.e. '/foo', '/bar'

The issue I'm running into is that when they visit new pages, I'm trying to pass the token from the client back to the server (almost identical to how its done in this [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) ), verify the token & check if it has permission to view the webpage.

I'm trying to figure out the best (& most secure) way to do this. I've considered the following option:

- Construct a URL with the token, but I've heard this isn't good practice because the token is getting exposed and session hijacking becomes a lot easier.

I've been trying to pass the token in the request header, but from my understanding you can't add headers when the user clicks on a link to a different page (or if its redirected in javascript). The same issue applies to using POST.

What can I do to securely pass this information to the server and check permissions when a user clicks on a link to a different page?

Comment: You can set it in a cookie. That's what I'd probably do.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks so much for the reply. I need the information on the server, but sessions are something I haven't thought of. That doesn't seem like it will work though because even if I store a client's token *or* custom uid on the server, the client will still need to send one of them in order to access the right session data. This still makes session hijacking really easy..

Comment: I am facing the same problem, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 27):

You can get the accessToken (idToken) on client side by:

```
var accessToken = null;

firebase.auth().currentUser
    .getIdToken()
    .then(function (token) {
        accessToken = token;
    });
```

and pass it in your request headers:

```
request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
```

and on your server side get the token with your prefered method and authenticate the request with Firebase Admin SDK, like (Node.js):

```
firebaseAdmin.auth()
    .verifyIdToken(accessToken)
    .then(decodedIdToken => {
        return firebaseAdmin.auth().getUser(decodedIdToken.uid);
    })
    .then(user => {
        // Do whatever you want with the user.
    });
```

Comment: Do you actually have to create the token before getting I can retrieve it on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it looks like we're meant to use `httpsCallable()` client-side to get an object pre-authorized to talk to your endpoint.

eg:

```
// # ./functions/index.js
exports.yourFunc = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // Checking that the user is authenticated.
  if (!context.auth) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
      'while authenticated.');
  }
  // ... rest of your method
});
```

```
// ./src/models/addMessage.js
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/functions");

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FUNCTIONS PROJECT ID ###'
  databaseURL: 'https://### YOUR DATABASE NAME ###.firebaseio.com',
});
var functions = firebase.functions();

// This is the new code:
var yourFunc = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('yourFunc');
yourFunc({foo: bar}).then(function(result) {
  // ...
});
```

From [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function)