# How to fix Error TS2339: Property 'authToken' does not exist on type

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Ionic App which is based on Firabase Realtime DB. When trying to start the app im getting this error message.

*[ng] ERROR in src/app/data-service.service.ts(14,36): error TS2339: Property 'authToken' does not exist on type '{ apiKey: string; authDomain: string; databaseURL: string; projectId: string; storageBucket: string; messagingSenderId: string; }'.*

It seems like there is something wrong with the Firebase authentification. But I could not figure out how to fix it.

**data-service.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment  } from '../environments/environment';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataServiceService {
  userId: any;
  userName: any;
  databaseUrl = environment.firebase.databaseURL;
  authToken = environment.firebase.authToken;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello DataServiceService Provider');
    console.log(this.databaseUrl);
    console.log(this.authToken);
    this.userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
    if (!localStorage.getItem('currentUserShift')) {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUserShift', JSON.stringify({ periods: {} }));
    }
    if (!localStorage.getItem('pendingShifts')) {
      localStorage.setItem('pendingShifts', JSON.stringify([]));
    }
  }

  setUserId(userId) {
    console.log('setUserId ');
    this.userId = userId;
    localStorage.setItem('userId', userId);
  }

  getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
  }

  getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
  }

  setUserName(userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
  }

  updateLocalCurrentUserShift(currentUserShift) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentUserShift', JSON.stringify(currentUserShift));
  }

  getLocalCurrentUserShift() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUserShift'));
  }

  async insertUserCurrentShiftToPendingShifts(currentShift) {
    const pendingShifts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pendingShifts'));
    pendingShifts.push(currentShift)
    localStorage.setItem('pendingShifts', JSON.stringify(pendingShifts));
    this.updateLocalCurrentUserShift({ periods: {} });
    await this.insertPendingShiftsToFirebase();
    // localStorage.setItem('currentUserShift', JSON.stringify({}));
  }

  async insertPendingShiftsToFirebase() {
    const pendingShifts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pendingShifts'));
    console.log('pendingShifts:', pendingShifts);
    const failedToBeSentPendingShifts = [];
    for (let i = 0 ; i < pendingShifts.length ; i++) {
      try {
        const key = await this.insertUserCurrentShifttoHistory(pendingShifts[i]);
        console.log('key' , key);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error while inserting into firebase', JSON.stringify(err));
        failedToBeSentPendingShifts.push(pendingShifts[i]);
      }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('pendingShifts', JSON.stringify(failedToBeSentPendingShifts));
    return true;
  }

  createFirebaseId() {
    return firebase.database().ref('/dummy').push().key;
  }

  getProducts() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/products/.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  }

  getOrganizations() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/organizations/.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  }

  insertUser(data) {
    return this.http.put(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${data.uId}.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`, data);
  }

  // an API to insert product views with firebase generated key
  insertProductViewAnalaytics(data) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/product_views.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`, data);
  }

  getProductViewsForUser() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/product_views/.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  }

  getUserOrganization() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/organization/.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  }

  fetchUserName() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/userName/.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  }

  // updateUserName(data) {
  //   return this.http.patch(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`, data);
  // }

  // an API to insert product views with custom timestamp based key
  insertProductViewAnalayticsTimestamp(data) {
    return this.http.put(`${this.databaseUrl}/product_views_timestamp/${data.scannedAt}.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`, data);
  }

  // insertUserCurrentShift(data) {
  //   return this.http.patch(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/currentShift.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`, data);
  // }

  // updateUserCurrentShift(data) {
  //   return this.http.patch(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/currentShift.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`, data);
  // }

  // getUserCurrentShiftStartTime() {
  //   return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/currentShift/currentPeriodStartedAt.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  // }

  // getUserCurrentShiftStatus() {
  //   return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/currentShift/status.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  // }

  // insertUserPeriods(data) {
  //   return this.http.post(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/currentShift/periods.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`, data);
  // }

  // getUserCurrentShift() {
  //   return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/currentShift.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  // }

  getPendingShifts() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pendingShifts'));
  }

  async insertUserCurrentShifttoHistory(data) {
    data.userId = this.userId;
    // return firebase.database().ref('/shiftHistory').push(data).key;
    if (data.startedAt && data.endedAt) {
      return this.http.post(`${this.databaseUrl}/shiftHistory/.json${this.authToken ? ('?auth=' + this.authToken) : ''}`, data).toPromise();
    } else {
      console.log('invalid data found, not inserting into firebase', JSON.stringify(data));
      return null;
    }
  }

  // removeUserCurrentShift(){
  //   return this.http.delete(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/currentShift.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  // }

  getUserWorkTimeHistory() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/shiftHistory.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}&orderBy="userId"&equalTo="${this.userId}"`);
  }

  insertUserCurrentLocation(data) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/locationHistory.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`, data);
  }

}
```

***environment.prod.ts***

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

***environment.ts***

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the `environment.ts` here:

```
import { environment  } from '../environments/environment';
```

which contains the following:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  }
};
```

There is no `authToken` property inside the `environment` object. That's why you got that error.

Comment: Do you know how I can get the authToken on Firebase?

Comment: are you talking about this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova?

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195612/how-to-pass-firebase-auth-token-from-client-to-server?

Comment: Seems like thats something different. Somehow this authToken was used to connect to Firebase: fetchUserName() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/userName/.json${this.authToken?('?auth='+this.authToken):''}`);
  }

Comment: What version of firebase are u using?

Comment: I think you are using an old version of firebase, because to connect to the database you only need to do `var database = firebase.database();` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: "firebase": "^5.9.4",

Comment: I changed it to: fetchUserName() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.databaseUrl}/users/${this.userId}/userName/.json`);
  }

Comment: Now im getting this: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://.....firebaseio.com/organizations/.json' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:8100' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Comment: Just connect like this var database = firebase.database(); why are u using http post request?

Comment: How do I do it exactly with var database = firebase.database();? Sorry, I am completely now to this.

Comment: It's okay just check this link firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write it tells you step by step how to connect and retrieve the data u need