# Is it possible to share the same firebase login token between iOS and an embedded webview?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Scenario: a native iOS app is using Firebase. There is also a web app that uses Firebase. For a modal within the iOS app, we'd like to render a WKWebView loading a page from our web app, *logged in as the same user*.

If it's possible, I'd like to inject the iOS app's "auth token" into the webview so it can log in and interact with Firebase itself.

A solution that would work is to fetch a [custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) via a cloud function whenever we show the webview. This isn't ideal for our use case.

Is there any way to do it locally, using the iOS app's existing session, perchance? There's `getIDTokenResult`, but that isn't a token that can be used to authenticate another session AFAICT.

I realize it might not be possible for security reasons, which is fine, if so. I'm not looking for a hack, just a legitimate API I might be missing.

Comment: Could you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195612/how-to-pass-firebase-auth-token-from-client-to-server), does getIDToken works for you?