Authenticate to Firebase Auth in embedded WebView
I am building an iOS application where users have to sign in using Firebase Auth.
Is it possible to embed a web view in my iOS application that offer web based authentication for the user, instead of building the view in native code? I have looked at the Firebase auth docs, and I can not figure out if Firebase offers something like this at all.
Using a simple web view to obtain the access token would be much easier than building the login in native code (I am aware of FirebaseUI but it is also built using native code, and the experience left a lot to be desired).
Auth0 offers web view authentication out of the box with webAuth. The Ticketmaster iOS app does exactly what I want, as illustrated in the image below.


This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727395/firebase-auth-in-a-flutter-app-with-webview, as does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70040782/is-it-possible-to-share-the-same-firebase-login-token-between-ios-and-an-embedde (though sadly that one is unanswered),
