# Is there a way to send the verification email with the Firebase Admin SDK from my Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Is there a way to send the email verification email from my server ?

This is how it's done on the client:

```
authData.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
```

Is there a way to do it on the server ?

Comment: Similar post (unanswered for now): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/cWdF8gkOH3w

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Similar indeed although I think it's important to point out that my issue is with Email verification, the other gentleman's issue being with Phone authentication.

Comment: Whoops, good point. Given that we just launched phone auth, I tend to over-interpret things as that. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ^^ Regardless, Gio from Firebase Support told me there was currently no way to send the verification email from the server. Is this a feature that's on Firebase's radar or not at all ? I already ended up reworking my code to to send the email using the firebase client SDK, but I am still curious :-)

Comment: I just checked all the docs, because I fully expected to be able to send those verification messages from the Admin SDK. But indeed: it doesn't seem to be there. I'd recommend [you file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Done ^^

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*firebaser here*

To my surprise there currently is no option to send verification email from within the Admin SDK. I'd recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

What you **can** do from the Admin SDK is [*update* a user profile to mark their email as verified](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user). This allows you to take control of the entire verification flow if you want to, finishing with a call to `admin.auth().updateUser(...)` (on Node.js, see the link for other supported languages).

Comment: Hi, was this added in the end ?

Comment: I cannot find evidence that it was added, and the more I thought about the problem, the more it made sense to keep this client-side, and the more my server-side admin approach seemed unnecessary. Re-sending of verification emails should really be handled by an error / button generated client-side when authentication is checked client-side.

Answer (score 10):

I just came across the same problem as you. There is a function to generate the verification link using user's email address.

I used this function on an array of email addresses, then load the result to my mail automation API to send mails out. This function is weirdly not documented:

```
admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink([EMAIL_ADDRESS])
```

Comment: [Email Action Link Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links)

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
axios.post('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=[API_KEY]',
    { requestType: 'VERIFY_EMAIL', idToken: response.data.idToken }
)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-send-email-verification