# Send firebase auth verification email using javascript and getuser

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send an email verification to users using firebase auth admin. All examples seem to use firebase.auth().currentUser;, however, in my case I am logged in as an admin user viewing a custom dashboard list of users to take action on rather than being logged in as an individual user.

I can successfully change a user record using this approach by passing in the UID to the updateUser method and the changes... e.g.

```
let userRecord = await fbAuth.updateUser(blogUID, {
          email: req.body.BloggerEmail
})
```

and can retrieve the userdetails of the user I want using:

```
    var userA = await fbAuth.getUser(blogUID)
```

However, the user object returned by this method does't allow me to call the sendEmailVerification method (it appears getUser doesn't return the same object type as getCurrentUser

```
    try {
        var userA = await fbAuth.getUser(blogUID).sendEmailVerification()
        console.log("Sent new verification email");
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error sending verification email " + error);
    }
```

[this fails, sendEmailVerification is not a method]

Official Reference Doc I've tried to use:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code uses the Admin SDK to look up a user by their UID, it can only call methods from the Admin SDK. You can't simply match methods from the Admin SDK and the client-side SDKs.

Since the Admin SDK doesn't have a method to send a verification email (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547671/is-there-a-way-to-send-the-verification-email-with-the-firebase-admin-sdk-from-m/44557980#44557980)), you will either have to let the client do this, or implement your own email verification flow. See [firebase admin SDK create user and send verification email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882626/firebase-admin-sdk-create-user-and-send-verification-email)

Comment: I've reviewed the article - this makes sense, I will also raise another change request to Firebase.