# Firebase: how to send reset-link through email template sent from nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

> I implemented sending emails via nodemailer.
>
> Now when I **create new user**, that new user get "welcome email".
>
> Problem is cus that "welcome email" should contain option for
>   resetting password.
>
> How to add **Firebase Resetting link** in nodemailer email template?

- This is my Email Template code for nodemailer

  ```
  const output = `
   <p>You have access to the Church Mutual Assignment Tool.</p>
   <p>Follow this link to create new password for your account ${userRecord.email}:</p>
     <a href="${resetPasswordLink}">
       ${resetPasswordLink}
     </a>
     <p>Thanks,</p>
     <p>Your Church Mutual Assignment Tool team</p>
   `
   let message = {
     from: 'nyik6nntutmq3vz6@ethereal.email',
     to: `${user.email}`,
     subject: 'Welcome to the Church Mutual Assignment Tool',
     text: 'Plaintext version of the message',
     html: output
   }
  ```
- This is my Nodemailer code:

  ```
    var mailer = require('nodemailer')
    var mailConfig = {
    host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: 'nyik6nntutmq3vz6@ethereal.email',
      pass: '3cbRjkZdPquDqA725s'
    }
  }

  var transporter = mailer.createTransport(mailConfig)

  module.exports = transporter
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Admin SDK now has some methods that allow you to do just this exact thing. Check out the docs on the [email action links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links), specifically the "*Generate password reset email link*" section.

```
// Admin SDK API to generate the password reset link.
const email = 'user@example.com';
admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(email, actionCodeSettings)
    .then((link) => {
        // Do stuff with link here
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Some error occurred.
    });
```

Full disclosure - I haven't actually used any of those functions, and I'm a little concerned that the page in question refers a lot to mobile apps - so you *might* have to pass it the mobile app config.

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
    // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for
    // this URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
    url: 'https://www.example.com/checkout?cartId=1234',
    // This must be true for email link sign-in.
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOS: {
        bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
    },
    android: {
        packageName: 'com.example.android',
        installApp: true,
        minimumVersion: '12'
    },
    // FDL custom domain.
    dynamicLinkDomain: 'coolapp.page.link'
};
```

On the other hand, the page also says these features provide the ability to:

> Ability to customize how the link is to be opened, through a mobile
>   app or a browser, and how to pass additional state information, etc.

Which sounds promising, allowing it to open in the browser... but if you are developing for web - and the function errors out when not provided iOS/Android information... then I'm afraid you'll have to do it the [old fashioned approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325629/firebase-how-to-send-a-password-reset-email-backend-with-nodejs) and create your own implementation... but I'm leaning towards this `.generatePasswordResetLink` should work for you.