# How to fix "admin.auth(...).sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function" Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

console.log('Entrou no resetPasswordRoutes.js');

// Rota para enviar o e-mail de redefinição de senha
router.post('/reset-password', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Rota de redefinição de senha acessada');

  const { email } = req.body;
  console.log('Email:', email);

  try {
    const actionCodeSettings = {
      url: 'https://www.example.com/?email=' + email, // URL para redirecionamento após a redefinição      de senha
      iOS: {
        bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
      },
      android: {
        packageName: 'com.example.android',
        installApp: true,
        minimumVersion: '12'
      },
      handleCodeInApp: true
    };

    // Enviar e-mail de redefinição de senha com as configurações personalizadas
    await admin.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email, actionCodeSettings);

    res.json({ message: 'E-mail de redefinição de senha enviado com sucesso' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'Falha ao enviar o e-mail de redefinição de senha', error:     error.message });
  }
});

// Rota para confirmar o reset da senha
router.post('/confirm-reset-password', async (req, res) => {
  const { code, newPassword } = req.body;

  try {
    await admin.auth().confirmPasswordReset(code, newPassword);
    res.json({ message: 'Senha redefinida com sucesso' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'Falha ao redefinir a senha', error: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

for some reason, it says my function doesn't exist. I get the logs on my server that the route was accessed and the log that returns the email used, put testing on Postman I get the error: "admin.auth(...).sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function"

Tried doing it through the Firebase console and it worked I got the email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase : How to send a password reset email backend with NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325629/firebase-how-to-send-a-password-reset-email-backend-with-nodejs)

Comment: try importing `const { getAuth } = require('firebase-admin/auth');` then call `getAuth().confirmPasswordReset`

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Admin Auth API, please note that there is no `sendPasswordResetEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)`. Such a method exists only in client-side SDKs for web and mobile. If you check the official documentation for [resetting a password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_password_reset_email_link), you'll see that you have to call `generatePasswordResetLink(userEmail, actionCodeSettings)`:

```
// Admin SDK API to generate the password reset link.
const userEmail = 'user@example.com';
getAuth()
  .generatePasswordResetLink(userEmail, actionCodeSettings) //
  .then((link) => {
    // Construct password reset email template, embed the link and send
    // using custom SMTP server.
    return sendCustomPasswordResetEmail(userEmail, displayName, link);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Some error occurred.
  });
```

Comment: Hey João. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?