# what is the authentication flow for a firebase and mean stack architecture?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am doing a project with angular as the front end and nodejs as the backend.

The database and authentication mechanisms are managed by firebase cloud.

The problem is i am stuck with the authentication mechanism.
It seems there are a lot of ways we can manage authentication using firebase.

I want my backend to deal with the authentication part, and i am using a email and password ecosystem for authentication.

But it seems that there is 2 npm packages one for angular [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) and another one for nodejs [firebase-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin).

I am in a mess to determine what method to use and how to use it effectievly to manage the authentication flow here, due to overflow of resources.

There seems to be `signInWithUserNameAndPassword` in firebase and there seems to be `signInWithCustomToken` in the firebase-admin.

Can anyone show me the right path to go through?

I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882626/firebase-admin-sdk-create-user-and-send-verification-email) but i don't know why we need to pass the token back to client and then pass it to admin side again for verification?

The client side in my app is a web project.
Is there any mistake on my understanding?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will use `signInWithUserNameAndPassword` method. A token will be returned to you which you can store in `localStorage` which is security wise a bad idea but is okay for simple projects for practice. Alternatively, you can use `angular-persistence` or similar libraries to persist your state. Then, you can authenticate a user with whether his/her token is present in state or not.

Answer (score 1):

`firebase-admin` doesn't support any user authentication APIs. So you must do your authentication at the client-side using the `firebase` package, and the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` API it provides: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

Comment: But how do we cross check it and all.

Comment: i have used client side firebase npm package in node js .